# Linked List, Count Objects with specific condition, Java Game Development

Tags: java, linked-list, counter

**Good Afternoon**

I am developing a Java 2D game, I am currently building an inventory system, the issue is how to get the correct count of objects in my linked list, meaning that how can I count how many "Swords" does the player have, the objects in this list are called items, and they differ in their TYPE value, (TYPE BEEN AN ENUM), so how can I count the amount of items that have a TYPE.sword VALUE?

I tried using a for loop within my tick method, which is the one that helps me update specific functions within a class, so by adding the following method into the tick method I am updating it all the time, to get the current amount of "swords", Currently the game is just giving a never ending count amount, I think it is due to the never ending loop, because the counter is re-calculating the size and adding it to the older one.

```
public void slotCounter(){
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.item.size(); i++){
        GameItem tempItem = handler.item.get(i);
        inventory[tempItem.getInvSlot()]++;

    }
}
```

F.W.I.: Handler is the class that countains all the linked list in the game, item been one of them.

Comment: the inventory array is the one that stores the count values and displays it to the player.

Comment: aren't you already getting the count of your linked list using `size()`?

Comment: I am, the thing is that I only want to count the objects with the TYPE sword, in that list there are other objects as well

Comment: Try stepping though the objects using a debugger